# How to regain an interactive shell that was disconnected via SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, shell, putty

Scenario:

I am on windows, using putty to login to a root shell. It is currently running an interactive process which prompts for input to continue. Typical interactive process, its probably waiting on the next standard in prompt.

I lose my Wifi connection. And I reconnect to the internet with a completely different IP (from a 3G connection now). How can I resume this session? I need to get back into that shell for a number of reasons. One being that I really hate losing my context/history for each putty window every time I disconnect, which may be often. And of coursse, most dire is to be able to get back to interactive processes that are currently waiting for input.

In short:

- Disconnected from internet
- Connection is therefore closed or timedout with server
- I come back to the internet on a new IP
- I want to regain the same shell, and in its last/current state. So if an interactive process is running, it should resume everything (eg: tail, vi, less + current input buffer)
- Is this scenario recoverable despite not having ran other processes first (eg: screen)

Answer (score 1):

No, your session is likely gone. You'd already mentioned `screen`, so you know that solutions like it and `tmux` will reduce the impact of a connection loss *the next time* this occurs. If you anticipate any long-running processes in the future, train yourself to run from within a screen session before executing.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check `screen`

After reconnecting, use `screen -ls` to show the detached screen

Use `screen -r` to attach to a screen